# stop ReconnectingClientFactory (XmlStreamFactory)

Tags: twisted

I tried to write a XMPP Client using this mentioned factories. Now my program only needs this connection during a short time. How can I make the Factory to stop reconnection attempts? Unfortunately stopTrying doesn't work. Do I have to disconnect running connections before?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

`ReconnectingClientFactory.stopTrying` does work.  Any time you have a question like this, you shouldn't just say "doesn't work".  You should explain your expectations, give a minimal example of the code you're trying, and explain how its behavior differs from your expectations.

For this case, here's an example which demonstrates how `stopTrying` meets my expectations, which are that after it is called, no further attempts will be made to establish the connection:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import ReconnectingClientFactory
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.python.log import startLogging
from sys import stdout

def main():
    startLogging(stdout)
    f = ReconnectingClientFactory()
    reactor.callLater(10, f.stopTrying)
    reactor.connectTCP('localhost', 12345, f)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This will run forever, but for the first 10 seconds of its run, it will be making new connection attempts (which all fail).  After `stopTrying` is called, it will stop making such attempts.